# Uncaught TypeError: window.getWidth is not a function . what is this error? how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I see following error for my website (via google Inspect). I need your help to understand the problem and how to fix it?
`script.js:137 Uncaught TypeError: window.getWidth is not a function`

```
at Object.check (script.js:137:23)
    at Object.initialize (script.js:58:14)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:442:14)
    at n (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2:14784)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2:15553)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2:9773)
    at HTMLDocument.B (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2:14348)
```

and following is script.js file content:

```
var TouchMask = {
    handlers: [],
    isbind: 0,
    ontouch: function(){
        var result = 1;
        TouchMask.handlers.each(function(fn){
            result = fn() && result;
        });
        
        if(result){
            document.removeEvent('touchstart', TouchMask.ontouch);
            TouchMask.isbind = 0;
        }
    },
    
    show: function(){
        if(this.isbind){
            return false;   
        }
        
        document.addEvent('touchstart', TouchMask.ontouch);
        
        this.isbind = 1;
    },
    register: function(handler){
        if(typeOf (handler) == 'function' && this.handlers.indexOf(handler) == -1){
            this.handlers.push(handler);
        }
    },
    unregister: function(handler){
        this.handlers.erase(handler);
    }
};


var JawallMenu = {
    initialize: function(){
        JawallMenu.isAndroidTable =  navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1 &&  navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') == -1;
        JawallMenu.isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window && !(/hp-tablet/gi).test(navigator.appVersion);
        JawallMenu.isTablet = JawallMenu.isTouch && (window.innerWidth >= 720);
        JawallMenu.enableTouch();
        JawallMenu.check();
        window.addEvent('resize', JawallMenu.check);
    },
    
    enableTouch: function(){
        if (JawallMenu.isTouch){
            var jmainnav = $('mainnav');
            
            if(!jmainnav){
                return false;
            }
            
            var jmenu = jmainnav.getElement('.menu');

            if(!jmenu){
                return false;
            }

            var jitems = jmenu.getElements('li.deeper'),
                onTouch = function(e){
                    var i, len, noclick = !this.retrieve('noclick');
 
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    // reset all
                    for (i = 0, len = jitems.length; i < len; ++i) {
                        jitems[i].store('noclick', 0);
                    }

                    if(noclick){
                        var jshow = this.addClass('hover').getParents('li.parent').addClass('hover');
                        jshow = jshow.append([this]);
                        jitems.each(function (jitem) {
                            if(!jshow.contains(jitem)){
                                jitem.removeClass('hover');
                            }
                        });
                    }
             
                    this.store('noclick', noclick);
                    this.focus();
                },
                onClick = function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    if(this.retrieve('noclick')){
                        e.preventDefault();

                        jitems.removeClass('hover');
                        this.addClass('hover').getParents('li.parent').addClass('hover');

                        TouchMask.hidetoggle();
                        TouchMask.show();
                    } else {
                        var href = this.getElement('a').get('href');
                        if(href){
                            window.location.href = href;
                        }
                    }
                };
            
            jitems.each(function(jitem){
                jitem.addEvent('touchstart', onTouch)
                    .addEvent('click', onClick)
                    .store('noclick', 0);
            });

            JawallMenu.resetmenu = function(){
                jitems.store('noclick', 0).removeClass('hover');
                return true;
            };

            TouchMask.register(JawallMenu.resetmenu);
        }
    },
    
    oldWidth: 0,
    
    check: function(){
        var wwidth = window.getWidth();
        if(wwidth == JawallMenu.oldWidth){
            return;
        }
        
        JawallMenu.oldWidth = wwidth;
        
        var jmainnav = $('mainnav');
        
        if(!jmainnav){
            return;
        }
        
        var jmenuinner = jmainnav.getElement('.menu-inner'),
            jmenu = jmainnav.getElement('.menu');
            
        if(!jmenuinner || !jmenu){
            return;
        }
        
        //check if we have to implement scroll
        if (jmenu.offsetWidth > jmenuinner.offsetWidth) {
            jmenu.setStyle('float', 'left');
            
            if(!window.menuIScroll){
                var jprev = jmainnav.getChildren('.navprev')[0] ||  new Element('a', {
                        'href': 'javascript:;',
                        'class': 'navprev'
                    }).inject(jmainnav).addEvent('click', function(){
                        if(window.menuIScroll){
                            window.menuIScroll.scrollToPage('prev');
                        }
                        
                        if(JawallMenu.jcitem){
                            JawallMenu.jcitem.fireEvent('shide');
                            JawallMenu.jcitem = null;
                        }
                    }),
                    jnext = jmainnav.getChildren('.navnext')[0] ||  new Element('a', {
                        'href': 'javascript:;',
                        'class': 'navnext'
                    }).inject(jmainnav).addEvent('click', function(){
                        if(window.menuIScroll){
                            window.menuIScroll.scrollToPage('next');
                        }
                        
                        if(JawallMenu.jcitem){
                            JawallMenu.jcitem.fireEvent('shide');
                            JawallMenu.jcitem = null;
                        }
                    }),
                    checkNav = function (){
                        if(window.menuIScroll){
                            jprev.setStyle('display', window.menuIScroll.x >= 0 ? 'none' : 'block');
                            jnext.setStyle('display', (window.menuIScroll.x <= window.menuIScroll.maxScrollX) ? 'none' : 'block');
                        }
                    };
                
                window.menuIScroll = new iScroll(jmenuinner, {
                    snap: '.menu > li',
                    hScrollbar: false,
                    vScrollbar: false,
                    onRefresh: checkNav,
                    onScrollEnd: checkNav,
                    useTransform: false,
                    onScrollStart: function(){
                        if(JawallMenu.jcitem){
                            JawallMenu.jcitem.fireEvent('shide');
                            JawallMenu.jcitem = null;
                        }
                    },
                    overflow: ''
                });
                
                checkNav();
                
                var jactive = jmenu.getChildren('.active')[0];
                if(jactive){
                    window.menuIScroll.scrollToElement(jactive);
                }
            }
            
            if (window.menuIScroll) {
                window.menuIScroll.refresh();
            }
        } else {
            if (window.menuIScroll) {
                window.menuIScroll.scrollTo(0, 0, 0);
            }
            
            jmenu.setStyle('float', '');
        }
        
        //check if the mobile layout, we change html structure
        if(wwidth < 720){
            if(JawallMenu.jcitem){
                JawallMenu.jcitem.fireEvent('shide');
                JawallMenu.jcitem = null;
            }
            
            jmenuinner.setStyle('overflow', 'hidden');
            
            jmenu.getChildren('.deeper > ul').each(function(jsub){
                var jitem = jsub.getParent(),
                    sid = null;
                    
                jsub.store('parent', jitem).addClass('jsub').inject(jmainnav).setStyle('position', 'absolute');
                
                if(!JawallMenu.isTouch){
                    //add mouse event to show/hide sub on desktop
                    jitem.addEvent('mouseenter', function(e){
                        clearTimeout(sid);
                        
                        if(jsub.getStyle('display') != 'none'){
                            return false;
                        } else {
                        
                            if(JawallMenu.jcitem && JawallMenu.jcitem != jitem){
                                JawallMenu.jcitem.fireEvent('shide');
                            }
                        
                            jsub.setStyles({
                                display: 'block',
                                top: jmenuinner.getHeight()
                            });
                            
                            jitem.addClass('over');
                            
                            JawallMenu.jcitem = jitem;
                        }
                    }).addEvent('mouseleave', function(){
                        clearTimeout(sid);
                        sid = setTimeout(function(){
                            jitem.fireEvent('shide');
                        }, 100);
                    });
                    
                    jsub.addEvent('mouseenter', function(){
                        clearTimeout(sid);
                    }).addEvent('mouseleave', function(){
                        clearTimeout(sid);
                        sid = setTimeout(function(){
                            jitem.fireEvent('shide');
                        }, 100);
                    });
                } else {
                    //add touch event for touch device
                    jitem.addEvent('touchstart', function(e){
                        if(jsub.getStyle('display') == 'none'){
                            e.stop();
                            
                            if(JawallMenu.jcitem && JawallMenu.jcitem != jitem){
                                JawallMenu.jcitem.fireEvent('shide');
                            }
                            
                            jsub.setStyles({
                                display: 'block',
                                top: jmenuinner.getHeight()
                            });
                            
                            jitem.addClass('over');
                            
                            JawallMenu.jcitem = jitem;
                            
                            TouchMask.hidetoggle();
                            TouchMask.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                
                jitem.addEvent('shide', function(){
                    clearTimeout(sid);
                    jsub.setStyle('display', 'none');
                    jitem.removeClass('over');
                    JawallMenu.jcitem = null;
                }).fireEvent('shide');
                
            });
            
            //only init once
            if(!JawallMenu.initTouch && JawallMenu.isTouch){
                
                jmainnav.addEvent('touchstart', function(){
                    if(JawallMenu.jcitem){
                        this.store('touchInside', 1);
                    }
                });
                
                TouchMask.hidesub = function(){
                    if(jmainnav.retrieve('touchInside')){
                        jmainnav.store('touchInside', 0);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        if(JawallMenu.jcitem){
                            JawallMenu.jcitem.fireEvent('shide');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    return true;
                };
                
                TouchMask.register(TouchMask.hidesub);
                TouchMask.hidesub();
                
                JawallMenu.initTouch = 1;
            }
            
        } else {
            
            JawallMenu.jcitem = null;
            
            jmainnav.getChildren('.jsub').each(function(jsub){
                var jitem = jsub.retrieve('parent');
                
                jitem.removeEvents('mouseenter').removeEvents('mouseleave').removeEvents('touchstart').removeEvents('shide');
                jsub.removeProperty('style').removeEvents('mouseenter').removeEvents('mouseleave').removeClass('jsub').inject(jitem);
            });
            
            jmenuinner.setStyle('overflow', '');
        }
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  if(window.menuIScroll){
    window.menuIScroll.refresh();
  }
    
  if(window.sidebarIScroll){
    window.sidebarIScroll.refresh();
  }
});


(function($){
    var groups = {
    },
    
    handler = function (group, value) {
        // ignore user setting for page with fixed option
        if ($(document.body).hasClass ('fixed-' + group)){
            return;
        }
        
        if (value) {
            if (groups[group]['type'] == 'toggle') {
                var cvalue = $.cookie ('ja-'+group);
                if (new RegExp ('(^|\\s)' + value+'(?:\\s|$)').test(cvalue)) {
                    $(document.body).removeClass (group + '-' + value);
                    cvalue = cvalue.replace (new RegExp ('(^|\\s)' + value+'(?:\\s|$)', 'g'), '$1');
                } else {
                    $(document.body).addClass (group + '-' + value);
                    cvalue += ' ' + value;
                }
                groups[group]['val'] = cvalue;
                // update cookie
                $.cookie ('ja-'+group, cvalue, {duration: 365, path: '/'});
            } else {
                // update value & cookie
                groups[group]['val'] = value;
                $.cookie ('ja-'+group, value, {duration: 365, path: '/'});
                // remove current
                document.body.className = document.body.className.replace (new RegExp ('(^|\\s)' + group+'-[^\\s]*', 'g'), '$1');
                $(document.body).addClass (group + '-' + value);
            }
        }
        
        // Make the UI reload by trigger resize event for window
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    };
    
    $.fn.toolbar = function(options){
        var defaults = {
            group: 'basegrid',
            type: 'single',
            val: 'm'
        },
        
        opt = $.extend(defaults, options);
        
        groups[opt.group] = groups[opt.group] || {};
        $.extend(groups[opt.group], {type: opt.type, val: opt.val});
        
        if (!$(document.body).hasClass ('fixed-' + opt.group)){
            var value = $.cookie('ja-'+opt.group);
            if (value) {
                groups[opt.group]['val'] = value; // setting exists, replace the default
                // add active class
                $(document.body).addClass (groups[opt.group]['val'].replace (/(^|\s)([^\s]+)/g, '$1' + opt.group + '-$2'));
            } else if(opt.val) {
                handler (opt.group, opt.val);
            }
        }

        // bind event for toolbar
        return this.bind('click', function () { handler (opt.group, this.id.replace ('toolbar-' + opt.group + '-', '')); return false; });
    };
    
})(window.$wall || window.jQuery);


(window.$wall || window.jQuery)(document).ready(function ($) {
    // enable menu responsive check
    if(!($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 9)){
        JawallMenu.initialize();
    }
    
    var bindevent = 'ontouchstart' in window && !(/hp-tablet/gi).test(navigator.appVersion) ? 'touchstart' : 'click',
        jtoggles = $('.btn-toggle'),
        jsidebar = $('#sidebar'),
        jtoggleactive = null;
        
    // toggle handle
    jtoggles.bind(bindevent, function (event) { 
        var jactive = $(this),
            jparent = jactive.parent();
            
        if (jparent.hasClass('active')) {
            jparent.removeClass ('active');
            // remove btn-toggle-active
            jtoggleactive = null
        } else {
            // remove other active
            jtoggles.parent().removeClass ('active');
            // add active for this toggle
            jparent.addClass ('active');
            // store
            jtoggleactive = jactive;        
        }
        
        if(typeOf (TouchMask.hidesub) == 'function'){
            TouchMask.hidesub();
        }
        TouchMask.show();
        
        return false;
    });
    
    
    jtoggles.parent().bind(bindevent, function(){
        if(jtoggleactive){
            $('body').data('touchInside', 1);
        }
    });

    TouchMask.hidetoggle = function(){
        if (jtoggleactive) {
            if($('body').data('touchInside')){
                $('body').data('touchInside', 0);
                return false;
            } else {
                // remove active
                jtoggleactive.parent().removeClass ('active');
                jtoggleactive = null;               
                return false;
            }
        }       
        return true;
    };
    TouchMask.register(TouchMask.hidetoggle);
    
    var rfpage = $('#josForm').hasClass('wform') && $('#k2Container').hasClass('k2AccountPage'),
        wmobile = false, //normal by default
        wmeditor = function(){
            if(!wmobile){
                var jmce = $('.mceLayout:first');
                if(jmce.width() > jmce.closest('.wcontrols').width()){
                    wmobile = true;
                    $('table.mceToolbar').each(function(){
                        $(this).find('> tbody > tr').css('white-space', 'normal').find('td').css({
                            position: '',
                            float: 'left',
                            display: 'inline-block'
                        });
                    });

                    $('.toggle-editor a').trigger('click').delay(300).trigger('click');
                }
            }
        },
        sidrfp = setTimeout(wmeditor, 350);

    // tracking status of btn-toggle
    $(window).resize (function() {
        JawallMenu.isTablet = JawallMenu.isTouch && (window.innerWidth >= 720);

        if (jtoggleactive) {
            if (jtoggleactive.css('display') == 'none') {
                // remove active
                jtoggleactive.parent().removeClass ('active');
                jtoggleactive = null;
            }
        }
        
        if (jsidebar.length) {
            if(JawallMenu.isTablet){
                jsidebar.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: ''
                });
            }

            jsidebar
            .add(jsidebar.find('.sidebar-inner'))
            .css('height', Math.max(80,  
                (window.innerHeight || $(window).height())
                - parseInt(jsidebar.css('top'))
                - parseInt(jsidebar.css('margin-bottom'))
                - parseInt(jsidebar.css('padding-bottom'))));
                
            if(window.sidebarIScroll){
                window.sidebarIScroll.refresh();
            }
        }

        if(rfpage){
            clearTimeout(sidrfp);
            sidrfp = setTimeout(wmeditor, 350);
        }
    });
    
    // scrollbar for sidebar if exist
    if (jsidebar.length) {
        jsidebar
            .add(jsidebar.find('.sidebar-inner'))
            .css('height', Math.max(80,  
                (window.innerHeight || $(window).height())
                - parseInt(jsidebar.css('top'))
                - parseInt(jsidebar.css('margin-bottom'))
                - parseInt(jsidebar.css('padding-bottom'))));
        
        window.sidebarIScroll = new iScroll(jsidebar.find('.sidebar-inner')[0], {vScrollbar: true, scrollbarClass: 'sidebarTracker', useTransform: false});

        if(JawallMenu.isTouch){
            var jsbtoggle = jsidebar.find('.btn-toggle:first');

            $('<div id="dummy-toggle"></div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                width: jsbtoggle.width(),
                height: jsbtoggle.height(),
            }).appendTo(document.body).bind(bindevent, function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                jsbtoggle.trigger(bindevent);
            });

            var lastScroll = 0,
                scrollid = null;

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('#dummy-toggle').css('top', lastScroll);

                if(JawallMenu.isTablet){
                    clearTimeout(scrollid);
                    scrollid = setTimeout(function(){
                        lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                        scrollid = setTimeout(function(){
                            if(lastScroll == $(window).scrollTop()){
                                jsidebar
                                    .css('top', lastScroll + parseFloat(jsidebar.css('top', '').css('top')))
                                    .css('position', 'absolute');

                                $(document).one('touchmove', function(){
                                    jsidebar.css({position: 'fixed', top: ''});
                                });
                            }
                        }, 100);
                    }, 100);
                }
            });
        }

        if(JawallMenu.isTablet && !JawallMenu.isBindTablet){
            $(document).on('touchmove', function(){
                jsidebar.css({position: 'fixed', top: ''});
            });

            JawallMenu.isBindTablet = 1;
        }
    }
    
    // check and load typography assert files if nessesary
    window.jtypo = jQuery('.item-pagetypography .item-content');
    
    if(!window.jtypo.length){
        window.jtypo = jQuery('.typography .itemBody');
    }
    
    if(window.jtypo.length){
        var css = document.createElement('link');
        css.type = 'text/css';
        css.rel= 'stylesheet';
        css.href= JADef.tplurl + 'css/jtypo.css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
        
        $.getScript(JADef.tplurl + 'js/jtypo.js');
    }
});
```

to understand it better please see the error directly via google inspect at following page:
http://test6.harfrooz.com/117-more/18376-top-20-ufo-sightings
This error made my menus disabled and more issues. I would appreciate for any help to solve this error.

Comment: What is `window.getWidth`? Where does it come from?

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I am fairly certain this has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window).

For normal javascript you can use:

- window.innerHeight - the inner height of the browser window (in
  pixels)
- window.innerWidth - the inner width of the browser window (in
  pixels)

Comment: Please don't write an answer for duplicates. Duplicates are closed and the duplicates are linked. You have to wait and earn some reputation, before you can vote to close a question as duplicate.